# How to retrieve information from Windows Phone 7 Marketplace

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm pretty new under Windows Phone 7 plataform. As I have never deployed an app into the marketplace, I wanna know if once I do, I can retrieve information about how many people have download my app and many other info like the Android market portal.

If not, is there any "wp7 market SDK" where I can get information throught a website for showing statistics about my app?

Answer (score 1):

In the AppHub you can see daily download and crash statistics. You can see how many paid vs trial downloads there have been in any given period and also get the stack traces for any crashes.

You can get download statistics programatically but I have never looked into this (I just know you can as I use the zTop app to check my statistics).